# Is there a way to check before adding module to JBoss using CLI?

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface

Is there a way to check module hasn't already been added before calling adding using JBoss CLI?

e.g.

```
module add --name=org.mysql --resources=/home/abc/drivers/mysql/MySQL5.jar



# Want to do similar check for module add
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=org.mysql:read-resource
   # Add it...
end-if
```

Reason is trying to add a module that already exists causes an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in **domain** mode, you can do that.

Here's how you can check a module's existence:

```
if (outcome != success) of /host=master/core-service=module-loading/:list-resource-loader-paths(module=your.module.name)
    echo install your.module.name ...   
    module add --name=your.module.name --dependencies=.. --resources=....jar
else 
    echo module your.module.name already installed
end-if
```

Answer (score 3):

There are only two options "add" and "remove". They fail when they are set in an "if" statement, so as far as I know the existence of the module cannot be checked. If the module does exist and "add" is executed it fails, the same happens if we try to remove a non-existing module. So finally I have created two scripts, one to add the modules and another one to delete them. You can check the "module" command documentation here: [cli command to add/remove AS modules](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4265)

Comment: Can you mabye supply a snipped showing this? i cant seem to get this to work 'Unrecognized arguments: [--dependencies, --name, --resources]'

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a try-catch statement:

```
try
module add --name=org.mysql --resources=/home/abc/drivers/mysql/MySQL5.jar
catch
end-try
```

Or if you want to overwrite it...

```
try
module remove --name=org.mysql
catch
end-try
module add --name=org.mysql --resources=/home/abc/drivers/mysql/MySQL5.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is going to create subfolders in `wildfly-24.0.0.Final\modules` for every module you install. So if you know the namespace definition of the module at hand you can check if the respective folder exists, e.g. for JDBC:

```
wildfly-24.0.0.Final\modules\com\oracle\jdbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to check if a module exists or not:

```
if (outcome == success) of /core-service=module-loading:list-resource-loader-paths(module=org.mysql) 
  echo "Module already exists"
else
  # Add the module if it doesn't exist
  module add --name=org.mysql --resources=/home/abc/drivers/mysql/MySQL5.jar
end-if
```