# How to check if module exists in Wildfly Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, command-line-interface, maven-plugin, wildfly-8

I want to check if a Wildfly module exists before adding.  I'm using Wildfly Maven Plugin `module add --name=x.y.z` but this fails if module already exists.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477353/is-there-a-way-to-check-before-adding-module-to-jboss-using-cli/45731925#45731925